# Appending output from a command to a variable in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to append an output of a command to a variable in Bash. My code is

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *
do
    lineInfo=`wc -l $file`
    echo "$lineInfo"
done
```

I understand how to "capture" the output of a command to a variable as I have done in this line by the use of backquotes.

```
lineInfo=`wc -l $file`
```

Is there a clean cut way I can place the output of that entire for loop into a variable in Bash? Or in each iteration of the for loop append the output of the wc command to linesInfo ? (Without redirecting anything to files) Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do overall? I suspect there is an easier way - maybe using a `bash array`.

Comment: You can change `lineInfo=\`some_command\`` to `lineInfo="$lineinfo \`some_command\`"`, or even better use array.

Comment: I just found out an easier way to achieve my desired result. Sorry for the troubles. I could just use wc -l *. That will give me a counter of my files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stores all the line infos (separated by commas) into one variable and prints that variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

total=""

for file in *
do
    lineInfo=`wc -l $file`
    total="$total$lineInfo, "  # or total+="$lineInfo, "
done

echo $total
```

Comment: You can also use `total+="$lineInfo, "`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I added this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the entire loop in the command substitution:

```
linesinfo=$(for file in *; do
        wc -l $file; done)
```

But of course, `wc` lets you run it on multiple files:

```
linesinfo=$(wc -l *)
```

While the output is reasonably machine-readable, a better approach in modern Bash would perhaps be to assign each result to a new element in an associative array.

```
declare -A linesinfo

for file in *; do
    linesinfo["$file"]=$(wc -l <"$file")
done
```

Somewhat surprisingly, use `"${!linesinfo[@]}"` to loop over the keys.

```
for file in "${!linesinfo[@]}"; do
    echo "'$file' size ${linesinfo[$file] bytes"
done
```

Demo:
https://ideone.com/FMGUyM

Associative arrays are not available in Bash v3 so this will not work out of the box on MacOS, which still ships a really old version of Bash.

Notice how running `wc` with a redirection produces just the actual number of lines (whereas `wc -l "$file"` would produce something like   `42 filename.txt` with leading spaces).